# Not able to update the text of a button after I select any of the optionsin the dropdown options. Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

For example, the text of the button is "please choose any of the below options", and the options are "Food", "Drinks", "Sleep. If i choose, "Food", I want "Food" to be the text instead of "please choose any of the below options".

I am using ng-bootstrap 4.1.0 and bootstrap 4.3.1.

1) The modules I have imported in mycomponent.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

2) Below is the content of mycomponent.html

```html
<script type="text/ng-template">

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
  });
</script>

<ng-template #content let-modal>

   <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz.com demo for this?

Comment: @alt255 Sorry but that is not possible. But if you want to know anything more about the code, I will surely tell you. I am surprised how difficult it is to find a solution for something very trivial

Comment: Are you sure this issue is related to Angular? I don't see any of the directives that appear on the demo page for NgBootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples). Specifically, `ngbDropdown`, `ngbDropdownToggle`, and `ngbDropdownMenu`. Additionally, I'm surprised by the jQuery code you included - that shouldn't be necessary (and in fact, should be avoided) with Angular.

Comment: @wanttomasterpython, you're using Angular, so, not use JQuery -really if you're using ng-bootstrap you must not use bootstrap (only bootstrap.css). Well, it's so easy to make some like `<button>{{selected?selected:'choose one option'}}</button>` -selected is a variable in your .ts that must give a value, see https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#displaying-data